# Plotly (python) subplot raises error when specifying row and column numbers as variables

Tags: python, plotly, subplot, plotly-python

**Original post:**

Thank you for spending your time reading this.

I'm trying to make a subplot figure but the following error raises

```py
If specified, the rows parameter must be a list or tuple of integers
length 1 (The number of traces being added)
Received: [[2]]
```

The rows and column parameters are being provided as a variable that I calculate from some conditions, but I'm certain they're integers. Here's the code:

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
# import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig2 = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, 
                    shared_xaxes=True, 
                    shared_yaxes=True, 
                    subplot_titles=("row1col1","row1col2", "row2col1","row2col2")
                    )
SPD = [100, 100, 100, 100, 75, 75, 75, 100, 75, 75, 100, 75]
TMP = [60, 60, 45, 45, 45, 60, 60, 60, 60, 45, 45, 45]

for run in range(1,13):
    rownum = (SPD[run-1] == 100)+1
    colnum = (TMP[run-1] == 60)+1
    df = some_dataframe
    fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                       x = df['x'],
                       y = df['y'],
                       mode = 'lines+markers',
                       line_width = 2
                       ),
                    row = rownum,
                    col = colnum,
#                     marker_size = 5)
                  )
                   
fig2.update_layout(height=600, width=1600, template = 'simple_white',
                   title_text="Stacked Subplots with Shared X-Axes")
fig2.show()
```

This code gives error in the definition of the `row` or `col` parameter as it is presented above, but if I hardcode a number (for example replace `rownum` and `colnum` with `1` and `2` it works.

Why does it not work with the variables?
Thank you again for your help.

---

The original post code as I posted it above indeed worked (provided `some_dataframe` has valid data), as kindly pointed by Roy2012, however, That was not the code I was running. It is a simplified version of a longer code which I stripped to include only the plotting part of interest. The variables `SPD` and `TMP` are above defined as lists, but in my true code they are series (actually columns of a dataframe).

When I define `rownum = (SPD[run-1] == 100)+1` in my true code it returns a `np.int32` object, while evaluating it in the above code it returns an `int` object. That is why it runs as posted and it wouldn't run in my true code. After figuring this out the solution was to define `rownum = (SPD.to_list()[run-1] == 100)+1` (and `colnum` accordingly)

I'm embarrased with you who kindly spent time to try and help me solve an issue that was ill-defined. This is a lesson for me for future posts here in the forums.

For reference purposes, I'm adding the full traceback of the error raised when defining `rownum` and `colnum` from series/dataframe columns instead of a list

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-b763d83160d2> in <module>
     32                        ),
     33                     row = rownum,
---> 34                     col = colnum,
     35 #                     marker_size = 5)
     36                   )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in add_trace(self, trace, row, col, secondary_y)
   1648             rows=[row] if row is not None else None,
   1649             cols=[col] if col is not None else None,
-> 1650             secondary_ys=[secondary_y] if secondary_y is not None else None,
   1651         )
   1652 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in add_traces(self, data, rows, cols, secondary_ys)
   1719         # Validate rows / cols
   1720         n = len(data)
-> 1721         BaseFigure._validate_rows_cols("rows", n, rows)
   1722         BaseFigure._validate_rows_cols("cols", n, cols)
   1723 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _validate_rows_cols(name, n, vals)
   1562 
   1563             if [r for r in vals if not isinstance(r, int)]:
-> 1564                 BaseFigure._raise_invalid_rows_cols(name=name, n=n, invalid=vals)
   1565         else:
   1566             BaseFigure._raise_invalid_rows_cols(name=name, n=n, invalid=vals)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _raise_invalid_rows_cols(name, n, invalid)
   1551         )
   1552 
-> 1553         raise ValueError(rows_err_msg)
   1554 
   1555     @staticmethod

ValueError: 
        If specified, the rows parameter must be a list or tuple of integers
        of length 1 (The number of traces being added)

        Received: [2]
```

Comment: I'm running your code, and it doesn't produce any error. (I'm getting a chart). Using Python 3.7.3 and plotly 4.8.1.

Comment: I'm using python 3.7.7, plotly 4.8.1 and jupyterlab 2.1.4 (but the error also occurred in v1.2.6). Any idea?

Comment: Could you please include the entire exception trace?

Comment: Of course, Adding it to the original post.
Also, I ran the code in spyder and gave the same error

Comment: The code in the exception and the code in the original code snippet are different. In the exception, it's "col = colnum[run-1]". In the original code, it's "row = rownumber, ". Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh sorry, good catch. I was trying to implement the variable in a different way but it's the same result. In the traceback I defined rownum and colnum as lists and accessed the elements with the iteration variable, returning an integer. I will update the code in the OP to reflect the traceback.

Comment: So ... can you share the exception for the original code (The one in the code snippet)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216807/discussion-between-sof-puar-and-roy2012).

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside that your code is **not** a minimal working example (and has many errors and/or room therefor), the main issue is likely to be in

```py
rownum = (SPD == 100)+1
```

where `SPD == 100` is evaluated to `False`, simply because `SPD` is a `List` and not a `numpy.ndarray`, as you might have thought. That is, the `==` operation is **not** applied in the element-wise sense and produces one value instead of an array.

Comment: Sorry, I acknowledge that. The code worked as Roy2012 pointed out but I got it messed up trying to test new ways to provide the 'row' and 'col' args. I'll have the code fixed and paste the corresponding traceback. 
Please look forward to a working code in a few minutes after I redo it again from scratch.